# Carriage return showing on HTML code

Tags: html, line-breaks, newline

I hate to ask but I had to. I have an html code. For some reason the carriage return is being saved and is being shown in my browser.

```
<div class="module">
    <p>Some data 

    some data <strong> more data
    more data</strong> and even more data </p>
</div>
```

Obviously I expect this to show:

Some data some data **more data more data** and even more data.

Instead, the paragraph is keeping the carriage returns / line breaks. 
I thought the problem was with Netbeans, so I downloaded Notepad++, but the problem persists. Thanks

I should add I am using this inside an .ctp file that belongs to CakePHP on a Windows machine, Apache WAMP server and that this data is explicit html, not echoed by php .

My current styling for the class is as follows:

```
.module{
     border: 1px solid   darkgrey;
     background-color: #F3F3F3;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding:5px;
     margin-bottom: 1em;
     overflow:  auto;

}
```

I am also adding any applicable styling that might be affecting my code, maybe you guys can spot it.

```
body {

          margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Tahoma';
          letter-spacing: 1px;

}

p, ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
          line-height: 160%;

}

p{
          white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
          white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
          white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
          white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
          word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

the white space styling on the p tag I added it as a prevention to users that input long words without spaces as a form to break the page.

Comment: Do you have any styles applied to your `<p>`? `white-space` in particular? And if you could give a link to your website, that would be splendid.

Comment: That doesn't cause it, so it must be something else. You can't provide us with a link to your site?

Comment: No, I am developing on localhost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *do* have `white-space:pre-wrap` on your `p`!

What did you think `white-space:pre-wrap` does? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Alright, that's it. Thank you so much. Now the task would be to deal with users that try to input looooooooooooooooooooonng words without any spaces. I had actually put that in order to avoid that.

Comment: In that case, all you need is the last line, `word-wrap: break-word;`. Remove the `white-space` ones.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word`, when it works, breaks words arbitrarily without inserting hyphens, violating the rules of English, for example. Some other approach should be considered, but it depends on what the user input might be, and belongs under a different question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You mean, like asking the user to type soft hyphens into the input? Pfff.